# How can I divide my thesis into two volumes with each volume containing three chapters?

Tags: sectioning

My code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands, twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[inner=4cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern, parskip}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}
\setlength{\parskip}{5pt}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{bbm,enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{label={(\roman*)}} % Global setting
\usepackage{soul,calc,xcolor,a4wide}
\usepackage{centernot,graphicx,algorithmic}
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels,linktocpage=true,colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\let\Hy@linktoc\Hy@linktoc@none
\makeatother
\hypersetup
{
    pdfauthor={.....},
    pdfsubject={},
    pdftitle={},
    pdfkeywords={},
   }

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{memhfixc}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\definecolor{nicered}{rgb}{.0588,.0941,.333}
\setsecheadstyle{\color{nicered}\Large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\normalsize\sffamily\raggedright}

\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt}

%%%FORMATING FOR CHAPTER
\makeatletter
\newlength\dlf@normtxtw
\setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth}
\def\myhelvetfont{\def\sfdefault{mdput}}
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter}
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
\sbox\feline@chapter{%
\resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
\colorbox{nicered}{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
}}%
\rotatebox{90}{%
\resizebox{%
\heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}%
{!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
\raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
}
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
\sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{% aka \rlap
\makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
}}
\makechapterstyle{daleif1}{
\renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so}
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{nicered}}
\renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
\renewcommand\printchaptername{}
\renewcommand\printchapternum{\null\hfill\feline@chm[2cm]\par}
\renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip}
\renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\chaptitlefont\raggedleft ##1\par}
}
\renewcommand{\secheadstyle}{\large \bfseries \color{nicered} 
\memRTLraggedright}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\rmnum}[1]{\romannumeral #1}
\newcommand{\Rmnum}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatother
\chapterstyle{daleif1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\captionnamefont{\small\sffamily\bfseries}
\captiontitlefont{\small\sffamily}

\makepagestyle{myruled}
\makeheadrule {myruled}{\textwidth}{2pt}
\makefootrule {myruled}{\textwidth}{2pt}{\footruleskip}
\makeevenhead {myruled}{}{\small\sffamily\leftmark}{}
\makeoddhead {myruled}{}{\small\sffamily\rightmark}{}
\makeevenfoot {myruled}{\small\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot {myruled}{}{}{\small\thepage}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{6mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-6.9mm}

\makeatletter % because of \@chapapp
\makepsmarks{myruled}{
  \nouppercaseheads\createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{
  \@chapapp\ }{.\ }
  \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
  \createmark{subsection}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
  \createmark{subsubsection}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
  \createplainmark {toc}{both} {\contentsname}
  \createplainmark {lof}{both} {\listfigurename}
  \createplainmark {lot}{both} {\listtablename}
  \createplainmark {bib}{both} {\bibname}
  \createplainmark {index}{both} {\indexname}
  \createplainmark {glossary}{both} {\glossaryname}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mar}[1]{\marginpar{\small \it #1}}
\marginparwidth 1 in

%\renewcommand\qed{$\blacksquare$}



\begin{document}
%% Some pages before contents
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\include{cover}
\cleardoublepage
\include{declaration}
\cleardoublepage
\include{acknowledgement}
\cleardoublepage
\include{dedication}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\begingroup
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{0.0 pt}
\pdfbookmark[0]{Contents}{toc}
\tableofcontents*
\endgroup
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{myruled}
% Here I want to add "Volume 1"
\include{Ch1}
\include{Ch2}
\include{Ch3}
% Here I want to add "Volume 2"
\include{Ch4}
\include{Ch5}
\include{Ch6}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many users here are willing to go through lots of code, but generally you would be better off to not include a lot of unnecessary stuff in your examples. Is it relevant that you `\usepackage{emheq}`? Is it necessary to change `\baselinestretch` or define commands like `\Xint`, `\pvint`, etc. etc. I never get to whatever it is you actually want to show! As I wrote many users here seem to actually be willing to go through it, so it is possible you will get answers anyway, but it would still be a good idea to make a minimal example instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have removed the unnecessary command as you mentioned in this context. Let us hope for some answers.

Comment: Perhaps use `\part{...}`? You can change it to produce "Volume I" instead of "Part I" with `\renewcommand{\partname}{Volume}`.

Comment: Thank you @imnothere. It is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your "Here I want to add ..." use `\book` or `\part`. In the preamble do

```
\renewcommand{\bookname}{Volume} % for \book
\renewcommand{\partname}{Volume} % for \part
```

See the `memoir` manual (`texdoc memoir`) if you want to change the appearance of your Volume page.

I'm assuming that you want the `\chapter` numbering to be continuous. If you want it to start again in your second Volume (which I do not advise) then put

```
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
```

after your second volume page.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. It is working now.